# Msg 15197, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_helptext, Line 107

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a procedure named dbo.CLRSPTest which i have encrypted. When I execute the procedure it gets executed but throws an error when I use sp_helptext CLRSPTest to view the code i.e `Msg 15197, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_helptext, Line 107
There is no text for object 'CLRSPTest'.`

Can anyone please help me out??? I am getting puzzled.

Comment: if you encrypt the procedure there is no text to display. Also for sqlclr procedures sp_helptext can't display anything. Do sp_helptext 'sp_helptext' to see what it does

Comment: But after encryption when sp_helptext is used, instead of that above error it should display "The text for object 'CLRSPTest' is encrypted."

Answer (score 1):

This error is raised by the following code in sp_helptext

```
 if (select count(*) from syscomments c, sysobjects o where o.xtype not in ('S', 'U')
     and o.id = c.id and o.id = @objid) = 0
   begin
     raiserror(15197,-1,-1,@objname) b
     return (1)
   end
```

This simply means that any object (not a table or system object) which does not have a line in `syscomments` will return this error.

Encrypted objects have a record in the `syscomments` table with `NULL` in the xtext field so they don't get caught by the earlier code. The message you get for those object comes from this query.

```
if (select count(*) from syscomments where id = @objid and encrypted = 0) = 0
  begin
    raiserror(15471,-1,-1,@objname)
    return (0)
  end
```

Now why do we get an error from the first one and no error for the second one... That can be explained by checking the data in `master..sysmessages`.

```
select error, severity, description 
  from master..sysmessages 
 where error in (15197, 15471) 
   and msglangid = 1033
```

This query returns:

```
error   severity    description
15197   16  There is no text for object '%s'.
15471   10  The text for object '%ls' is encrypted.
```

Here we see that error 15197 has severity 16 and error 15471 has severity 10. On [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx) it is explained that error levels 0-9 are not "raised" and that error level 10 gets converted to error level 0 for compatibility reasons.

So to conclude it all. **You get this error message because your procedure is a SQL CLR procedure** (which don't get any records in the `syscomments` table)